# how to refresh CuratorFramework when zookeeper reconnected to check node exists or not

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, bigdata

Hi in my application I started three instances of zookeeper. Now when 2 instances killed then zookeeper shutdown event occurs . Now when I started 1 instance then zookeeper comes in up state. but all empheral nodes deleted in this process.
But from client in reconnect event when I check is node exist then it returns few numbers instead of null.

So is this issue of CuratorFramework not refresh when reconnected. what should I do for this.